# Workflow Foundation Separate Schema

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, workflow, workflow-foundation

I'm working with the persistence and tracking services in Workflow Foundation and I thought it would be a good idea to use a separate schema in SQL Server just for workflow.

Unfortunately, it appears they hard-coded the default dbo schema name into their code. One example is the SqlTrackingService class. Due to the way they wrote the tracking classes, I can't override the methods to provide my own db query code.

I have thought about the following options, but some don't appear to be possible:

- Re-write tracking from scratch
- Disassemble and re-write tracking files (Licensing violation?)
- Some way to intercept and re-write sql query
- Some way to trick it into using a custom version of SqlCommand that filters CommandText
- Just go ahead and use the dbo schema for the WF stuff
- Use a completely separate database for WF.

Does anyone have any suggestions or options I haven't considered? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases I just accept the dbo scheme and sometimes move things into a separate database. As far as I know there is no way to intercept the commands and rewrite the scheme or table names but then I never tried either. If you want to rewrite, I did a port, SqlCeWorkflowPersistenceService, to SQLCe and LinqToSql. Feel free to use and/or modify it to fit your needs. See [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SqlCeWFPersistence) for the code. It does pretty much the same thing as the default SqlWorkflowPersistenceService except for the ownership part which is broken anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I guess using the dbo schema or using a different database is the easiest route. 

I did, however, find a way to intercept and rewrite sql queries. While not very clean, it does do what I want and probably has other uses as well.